# saving lists as single or separate files

Tags: python, string, list

My task is to:

> Develop a program that identifies individual words in a sentence, stores these in a list and replaces each word in the original sentence with the position of that word in the list.
>
> For example, the sentence 
>   ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY
>   contains the words ASK, NOT, WHAT, YOUR, COUNTRY, CAN, DO, FOR, YOU
>
> The sentence can be recreated from the positions of these words in this list using the sequence 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,3,9,6,7,8,4,5

I've done the first part of the task and so far I have this code:

```
sentence = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR 
YOUR COUNTRY"
s = sentence.split()
positions = [s.index(x)+1 for x in s]

my_list = ['ASK', 'NOT', 'WHAT', 'YOUR', 'COUNTRY', 'CAN', 'DO', 'FOR', 
'YOU', 'ASK', 'WHAT', 'YOU', 'CAN', 'DO', 'FOR', 'YOUR', 'COUNTRY']
unique = []
[unique.append(item) for item in my_list if item not in unique]

print("The sentence",sentence,"contains the words",unique)

print("It can be recreated from the positions of the words in this 
list",s,"using the sequence",positions)
```

Is this considered efficient? How can I make it more efficient?

However, my problem is the rest of the task:

> Save the list of words and the positions of these words in the sentence as separate files or as a single file.

I have no idea what it means. I did some research and I found out that it involves reading and writing to a file, but I don't have a clue what to do next.

Nevertheless I came up with this:

```
my_list = ['ASK', 'NOT', 'WHAT', 'YOUR', 'COUNTRY', 'CAN', 'DO', 'FOR', 
'YOU', 'ASK', 'WHAT', 'YOU', 'CAN', 'DO', 'FOR', 'YOUR', 'COUNTRY']
with open("task2.txt", 'w') as f:
f.write("\n".join(map(str, my_list)))
```

But I don't know what it does or how it relates to the task??? I need to be able to explain my code which I can't do since I don't understand it.

Can someone please fix my code? Thank you

Comment: Any particular reason this is tagged [tag:r]?

Comment: it came up in the suggested bar

Comment: StackOverflow knows best.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
s = sentence.split()
positions = [s.index(x)+1 for x in s]

map = {}
for w in s:
  map[w] = True

words = []
for w in map:
  words.append(w)

print(words)
```

Comment: the output isn't in the right order though, i need it in that particular order

Comment: I thought you want exactly ['ASK', 'NOT', 'WHAT', 'YOUR', 'COUNTRY', 'CAN', 'DO', 'FOR', 'YOU'] in that order? I am running it with Python 3.6

Comment: yeah, i ran it with python online and i got ['ASK', 'FOR', 'COUNTRY', 'DO', 'WHAT', 'CAN', 'YOU', 'NOT', 'YOUR']

Comment: i'll run it at school later with python 3.6 and hopefully it'll work

Comment: Try it on https://console.python.org/python-dot-org-console/console_frame/

Answer (score 2):

Since you've tagged this R, here's a solution in R.

```
sentence <- "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY"

find.words <- strsplit(sentence, " ")[[1]] # split string into 
words <- unique(find.words) # find unique words
# find positions of words in the unique vector
words.pos <- sapply(find.words, FUN = function(x, words) which(x == words), words = words)

sprintf("The sentence can be recreated from the positions of these words in the list %s using the sequence %s", 
        paste(words, collapse = " "), paste(words.pos, collapse = " "))

[1] "The sentence can be recreated from the positions of these words in the list ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU using the sequence 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 3 9 6 7 8 4 5"
```

Here is one way of how you could write it to a file.

```
# find position by word
pos.by.word <- sapply(words, FUN = function(x, fw) which(x == fw), fw = find.words)
# paste names together
concat.words.freq <- mapply(FUN = function(x, y) {
  paste(x, paste(y, collapse = " "))
}, names(pos.by.word), pos.by.word)

write.table(as.data.frame(concat.words.freq), file = "out.txt",
            row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

And `out.txt` looks like this:

```
ASK 1 10
NOT 2
WHAT 3 11
YOUR 4 16
COUNTRY 5 17
CAN 6 13
DO 7 14
FOR 8 15
YOU 9 12
```

Comment: haha is there any way you can convert this to python for me?

Comment: Sure, save the R code in a `word_list_pos.R`, create Python script with `import os; os.system("Rscript word_list_pos.R")` and run `python myscript.py`. :)

Answer (score 0):

I give you a possible solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict

words = defaultdict(list)
sentence = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY"
s = sentence.split()
for pos, word in enumerate(s):
    words[word].append(pos + 1)
```

Output:

```
In [20]: words
Out[20]: 
defaultdict(list,
        {'ASK': [1, 10],
         'CAN': [6, 13],
         'COUNTRY': [5, 17],
         'DO': [7, 14],
         'FOR': [8, 15],
         'NOT': [2],
         'WHAT': [3, 11],
         'YOU': [9, 12],
         'YOUR': [4, 16]})
```

Comment: what about if the order is important?

Comment: @RichaGeorge forget about it.. I thought another simpler solution